# SQL separate the count of one column

Tags: sql, database, count

I have a SQL table that contains three columns:

```
userId
userName
item
```

and I created this SQL query which will count all the items types of one user:

```
 select 
     count(ItemID) as 'count of all items types', 
     userId,
     userName
 from 
     userTable
 where 
     ItemID in (2, 3, 4)
     and userId = 1
 group by 
     userId, userName
```

The result will be like this:

```
+--------+----------+--------------------------+
| userId | userName | count of all items types |
+--------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1     | kim      |     25                   |
```

and I am looking for a way to separate the counting of itemes types, so the result should be like this:

```
+--------+----------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+
| userId | userName | count of item1 | count of item2 |  count of item3 |
+--------+----------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+
|  1     | kim      |     10         |       10       |   5             |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    userID,
    userName,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ItemID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_of_item1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ItemID = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_of_item2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ItemID = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_of_item3
FROM
    My_Table
GROUP BY
    userID,
    userName
```

Answer (score 2):

This is called conditional aggregation. Use CASE for this.

With COUNT:

```
select 
  count(case when ItemID = 1 then 1 end) as count_item1, 
  count(case when ItemID = 2 then 1 end) as count_item2, 
  count(case when ItemID = 3 then 1 end) as count_item3 
...
```

(`then 1` could also be anything else except null, e.g. `then 'count me'`. This works because `COUNT` counts non-null values and when omitting the `ELSE` in `CASE WHEN` you get null. You could also explicitly add `else null`.)

Or with SUM:

```
select 
  sum(case when ItemID = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as count_item1, 
  sum(case when ItemID = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as count_item2, 
  sum(case when ItemID = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as count_item3 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do it :

```
select userId,
           username,
           SUM(CASE WHEN ItemID = '2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Item2-Cnt,
           SUM(CASE WHEN ItemID = '3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Item3-Cnt,
           SUM(CASE WHEN ItemID = '4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Item4-Cnt
    FROM userTable
    GROUP BY userID, userName
```